# Kernel compilation and free space

Tags: hard-drive, memory, linux-kernel

I am compiling linux kernel 3.0.1

My operating system is **Ubuntu 11.04**

The source is in `/usr/src/linux-3.0.1`

Though there is no free space remain in `/` the compilation is still going on .. !

What is happening exactly ?? Should I stop it ?

Answer (score 1):

Are you compiling as root?  I don't know if the free space reported by `df` takes into account the typical 5% superuser reservation.

Also it could be the kernel hasn't flushed the disk cache yet.

<strike>It is also possible your `/usr` is mounted on a separate partition.  This is quite likely if you took the defaults during your Ubuntu install (unless something has changed since the last time I used Ubuntu...)</strike>

If you run out of disk space and the compilation fails, free up some disk space and resume the compilation by issuing the `make` command again.

Bad idea to let `/` run out of space.  I would try to address that ASAP.

Comment: Ubuntu has always defaulted to a single partition install.  It is not recommended to have a separate /usr.

Comment: `df` reports 100% used blocks when the reserved blocks are still available to the super-user, by experiment with *df (GNU coreutils) 8.15* on *Gentoo*.

Comment: Quote from the [Ubuntu 8.04 LTS Installation Guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/8.04/installation-guide/i386/apcs03.html): "For multi-user systems or systems with lots of disk space, it's best to put /usr, /var, /tmp, and /home each on their own partitions separate from the / partition." I guess it's reasonable to suspect separate `/usr`s still linger.